# Zurb foundation jquery dependencies

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation

I was wondering if anyone out there knew which js files from [zurbs foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) requires Jquery. I am building my functions.php file in wordpress and I want to set the dependencies for the scripts if they have any, so that they are guaranteed to load after the Jquery file. Here is a list of the files

- modernizer.js
- foundation.js
- app.js

Again which ones have dependancies on Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a bit old, so the question wouldn't be exactly the same now:

modernizer.js doesn't require jQuery, I think foundation & app did, but zurb has significantly changed the javascript files, including made their own fork of modernizer (modernizr.foundation.js) - the current (foundation 2.2) "preferred" load order is:

```
<head>  
<script src="js/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
...
...
<!-- end of container/all content -->

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<!-- all the jQuery dependent files begin with 'jquery.' and are separated so 
you can remove what you don't use  -->


<script src="js/jquery.reveal.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.orbit-1.4.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.customforms.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.placeholder.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tooltips.js"></script>

<!-- app.js is basic functions that you're supposed to edit - 
it requires jQuery to start as well  -->

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```